# Format of packets of H264 video for raw\raw\udp STB

Tags: video, udp, h.264

There is a lot of information about `RTP` payload format for `H.264` but I can't find anything about `raw\raw\udp`. It will be realy helpful If someone can explain to me how to pack (packet structure without udp header) and send `NAL units of H264 video to STB (only raw\raw\udp supported)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy.
I guess "raw\raw\udp" is just another name for mpegts. So you just need to send 188 bytes packets of .ts container over udp. It's works for me.